# JSoup select from HTML in unix

Tags: java, unix, select, syntax, jsoup

I have a program that extracts certain elements(article author names) from many articles, from the PubMed site. While the program works correctly in my pc (windows), when i try to run it on unix returns an empty list. I suspect this is because the syntax should be somewhat different in a unix system. The problem is the JSoup documentation does not mention something. Anyone know anything on this? My code is something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/" + pmidString).timeout(60000).userAgent("Mozilla/25.0").get();
            System.out.println("connected");
            Elements authors = doc.select("div.auths >*");
            System.out.println("number of elements is " + authors.size());
```

The final System.out.println always says the size is 0 therefore it cannot do anything more.

Thanks in advance

Complete Example:

```
protected static void searchLink(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> authorsMap,  HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> reverseAuthorsMap,
        String fileLine

        ) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException
{

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileLine.substring(0, fileLine.length() - 1 ));
            String pmidString = (String)jsonObj.get("pmid");
            System.out.println(pmidString);

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/" + pmidString).timeout(60000).userAgent("Mozilla/25.0").get();
            System.out.println("connected");
            Elements authors = doc.select("div.auths >*");
            System.out.println("found the element");

            HashSet<String> authorsList = new HashSet<>();
            System.out.println("authors list hashSet created");
            System.out.println("number of elements is " + authors.size());
            for (int i =0; i < authors.size(); i++)
            {


                // add the current name to the names list
                authorsList.add(authors.get(i).text());

                // pmidList variable
                HashSet<String> pmidList;
                System.out.println("stage 1");
                // if the author name is new, then create the list, add the current pmid and put it in the map
                if(!authorsMap.containsKey(authors.get(i).text()))
                {
                    pmidList = new HashSet<>();
                    pmidList.add(pmidString);
                    System.out.println("made it to searchLink");
                    authorsMap.put(authors.get(i).text(), pmidList);

                }
                // if the author name has been found before, get the list of articles and add the current
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Author exists in map");
                    pmidList = authorsMap.get(authors.get(i).text());
                    pmidList.add(pmidString);


                    authorsMap.put(authors.get(i).text(), pmidList);
                    //authorsMap.put((String) authorName, null);
                }

                // finally, add the pmid-authorsList to the map
                reverseAuthorsMap.put(pmidString, authorsList);
                System.out.println("reverseauthors populated");

            }

}
```

I have a thread pool, and each thread uses this method to populate two maps. The fileline argument is a single line that I parse as json and keep the "pmid" field. Using this string I access the url of this article, and parse the HTML for the names of the authors. The rest should work (it does work in my pc), but because the authors.size is 0 always, the for directly below the number of elements System.out does not get executed at all.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: By complete I don't mean include all the processing you want to do, but just provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this is actually a part of a big load of code, that i can't just paste here. I am pretty convinced the problem lies in the syntax inside the doc.select, and anything more that i can give you won't help you figure it out, because it will work unless you run it on unix. Thanks for your interest

Comment: The first snippet was a good start, but it needs a value for pmidString (and it should be in a class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried an [example](https://github.com/kyleburton/sandbox/blob/master/examples/java/jsoup/java/Test.java) doing exactly what you're trying:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    String docId = "24312906";
    if (args.length > 0) {
      docId = args[0];
    }

    String url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/" + docId;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(60000).userAgent("Mozilla/25.0").get();
    Elements authors = doc.select("div.auths >*");

    System.out.println("os.name=" + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    System.out.println("os.arch=" + System.getProperty("os.arch"));

    // System.out.println("doc=" + doc);
    System.out.println("authors=" + authors);
    System.out.println("authors.length=" + authors.size());

    for (Element a : authors) {
      System.out.println("  author: " + a);
    }
  }
}
```

My OS is Linux:

```
# uname -a
Linux graphene 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 
GNU/Linux
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

Running that program produces:

```
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
authors=<a href="/pubmed?term=Liu%20W%5BAuthor%5D&amp;cauthor=true&amp;cauthor_uid=24312906">Liu W</a>
<a href="/pubmed?term=Chen%20D%5BAuthor%5D&amp;cauthor=true&amp;cauthor_uid=24312906">Chen D</a>
authors.length=2
  author: <a href="/pubmed?term=Liu%20W%5BAuthor%5D&amp;cauthor=true&amp;cauthor_uid=24312906">Liu W</a>
  author: <a href="/pubmed?term=Chen%20D%5BAuthor%5D&amp;cauthor=true&amp;cauthor_uid=24312906">Chen D</a>
```

Which seems to work.  Perhaps the issue is with fileLine?  Can you print out the value of 'url':

```
System.out.println("url='" + "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/" + pmidString+ "'");
```

Since you're not getting an exception from your code, I suspect you're getting a document, just not one your code is anticipating.  Printing out the document so you can see what you've gotten back will probably help as well.

Comment: I did what you suggested and apparently I don't get the correct HTML back. The returned HTML is explaining that the site is blocking me for god knows why. At least i figured where the problem really is.
Thanks a lot for your help!